# How to make onEdit() script work on all rows modified when a list of values pasted from the clipboard?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where I want to track for each new row, the date when the value of a certain cell was first filled and also the date when any cell in that row is updated. So I have this script that does what I want:

```
function onEdit() {

 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var r = s.getActiveCell();

 // If it is first time keyword added, we will add the current date to "Date Added" Column 

 if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
   var r = s.getActiveCell();

   // We will if it is the first time the "Keyword" column has been written
   if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { 
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
     if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy");
       nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
 };

 // If there is any further change, then add/change the date in the "Date last modified" column 

 var r = s.getActiveCell();

  if( r.getValue() !== '' && r.getRow() !== 1){ // Disregard when it was just a new row that was inserted

    if( r.getColumn() != 5 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
    };

  };  
}
```

My problem is that whenever I come with a list of values and paste them in the empty rows space, the script seems to work for only the first row of all the rows for the new values that I added.

So if I come and I paste this:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5
```

I end with:

```
value1     2/11/2017     2/11/2017
value2
value3
value4
value5
```

But I would like that the script would have worked in such a way that I end with:

```
value1     2/11/2017     2/11/2017
value2     2/11/2017     2/11/2017
value3     2/11/2017     2/11/2017
value4     2/11/2017     2/11/2017
value5     2/11/2017     2/11/2017
```

Can anybody let me know what do I need to change/add in order to fix this behaviousr?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use can the activeRange instead of activeCell like so:

```
range = s.getActiveRange()
```

This will give you the range over which the new data was pasted, then you loop over each row in that range:

```
for(var i = 1; i<= range.getNumRows() ; i++){
   var r = range.getCell(i, 1)
   ...
}
```

**range.getCell(i,1)** will give the first cell in the active range when i = 1, second one below it when i= 2 and so forth. 
Note: The assumption here is you will paste the new list in one column at a time, especially when modifying column 2. So if you paste your data over a range of A2:C5, range.getCell(1,1) will give A2 and the code will assume Column 2 was not modified. If my assumption is incorrect, just modify the script to figure out if column 2 is in the active range and select that column.

```
function onEdit() {

 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 // Instead of getting activeCell we get the whole range
 var range = s.getActiveRange()

 //Use For loop to go through each row and add the time Stamp
 for(var i = 1; i<= range.getNumRows() ; i++){

   var r = range.getCell(i, 1) //Assumption here is that data is pasted in one column only
   // IF that is not always the case, you will have to get the range over which the data was pasted and select column 2

   if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
      //var r = s.getActiveCell(); calling it again doesnt change its the value
      // If it is first time keyword added, we will add the current date to "Date Added" Column  
      // We will if it is the first time the "Keyword" column has been written

     if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { 
        var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
        if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) {//is empty?
           var time = new Date();
           time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy");
           nextCell.setValue(time);
        }
      };
    };

    // If there is any further change, then add/change the date in the "Date last modified" column 
    // var r = s.getActiveCell(); calling it again doesnt change its the value
  if( r.getValue() !== '' && r.getRow() !== 1){ // Disregard when it was just a new row that was inserted
    if( r.getColumn() != 5 ) { //checks the column
       var row = r.getRow();
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy");
       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
     };

   };  
 }
}
```

PS: It is **not a good practice** to update one cell value at a time as done in this code. Instead use getValues and setValues to access and set values in a batch.Especially if users will paste a lot of data into the sheet.  http://googleappsscript.blogspot.com/2010/06/optimizing-spreadsheet-operations.html

Comment: Thank you incredibly much! This is absolutely what I needed to acomplish, and your assumption is mostly correct. Eventhough in the pasting situation there will not always be just one column, one of them will for sure be column 2. If it would not, I'm not interested in storing the first insert and last update dates until column 2 ifor that row s filled :)

Comment: I understand what you mean by it not being efficient. Most of the pasting situations will be 20-100 rows in one go, so I might revisit your best practice suggested approach. Thanks for mentioning it

Comment: something does not work right with the code as it is now. when I paste a big amount of rows(like 150-200), the date cells starts getiing filled row by row but after a certain number it stops half way. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: Scripts are getting time outed, the scripts can only be executed for a certain amount of time. You can check if this indeed is the case by viewing the execution transcript (Script Editor>View>Execution Transcripts). This is happening because you are accessing each cell one time at a time to paste your timestamp, instead select the range cells like range = getRange(1,1,150,1) and then set the timestamp to the range like so range.setValue(new Date());  Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range